# applicationBadgeNumber doesn't increment

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, foundation

So far I've found that I can't increment the app badge number through local notifications. So doing something like this:

```
self.notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;
```

won't really work.

If I say for example the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to be 7, it surely becomes 7, but if I set it like I'm doing over there, it just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Tested it and was able to use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1` to increment. Is there a particular reason you were going through the `UILocalNotification` and not `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`?

[Update]
Looked at the docs for [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **applicationIconBadgeNumber**
>   The default value is 0, which means "no change.” The application should use this property’s value to increment the current icon badge number, if any.

To me, this means that when handling a `UILocalNotification`, you should do:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber;
```